# How to select an equilibrium among the landscape of Nash equilibria in poker?

Tags: game-ai, game-theory, poker

Reading some articles on counterfactual regret minimization solutions of HULHE and HUNLHE poker published in the last decades -like [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01724.pdf), [2](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ebowling/papers/15science.pdf)- i was wondering what can be said about the different Nash equilibria, in heads-up poker to begin. First of all am i right to think that if both players play equilibrium strategies, possibly different, they both have 0 expectation, when averaging over both starting positions -dealer and small blind ? The reasoning is that neither can improve his expected utility by deviating so his expected utility is maximal given the other's strategy, but the game being symmetric no player can expect a utility greater than the other at an equilibrium, and the sum of expected utilities being 0 each player has 0 expected utility.

A priori HULHE poker has many equilibria, yet despite the a priori very different strategies, say $S$ and $S'$, and different payoffs for player 1 choosing strategies $S$ and $S'$ for any particular card distribution, in the long run all the different outcomes would even out to give 0 expected payoffs for both $S$ and $S'$. This observation leads me to wonder: how different can equilibrium strategies be ? For simple $n$-player games, like stag hunt or battle of the sexes, the different equilibria are well understood and there is a theory of equilibrium selection -introducing for instance the notions of payoff-dominance and risk-dominance. When passing to a complex game like poker there must be very intricate coincidences between the different kinds of strategy, very interesting tradeoffs, which must be computationally difficult to investigate and often surprising.

*Question:* Has there been research on the landscape of equilibrium strategies in poker, if only to propose a theory for selecting them, like in terms of risk of ruin or exploitativity ? Where "exploitativity" is a measure -to be defined, with different possible definitions- of how much a strategy exploits nonequilibrium strategies.

Of course this question can be considered in contexts intermediate between the simple $n$-player games mentioned above and the complicated one of poker. One can also consider yet more complex games. But it seems that HULHE poker is a good case to study. For the classical cases the selection of equilibria has been studied by [Harsanyi and Selten](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262582384/a-general-theory-of-equilibrium-selection-in-games/), but their methods look far from poker.

Thank you.